# Current search block: edit (-) link

Tags: 7, search

I'm using search api and solr, with facet api.
If I display a "current search block", if I click on a facet the system add to the block a "(-) facet name", and if I click to "(-)" it removes the facet from the search.
Is there a way to theme this behaviour? I want to display it as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `theme_facetapi_deactivate_widget` function in facetapi.theme.inc. Of course, you can override it in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
function hook_facetapi_deactivate_widget(&$variables) {
  return '';// fill with your required data
}
```